# Convert paths that start with "content//:" or "/data/.." to URI

Tags: android

I have two types of file paths, one I get from my sqlite db and one I derive locally.

The one that comes from db has the following format "content://mnt/sdcard/data/download/image1"
And the one locally is "/data/data/com.mytestapp/files/image1.png"

I need to convert both to URI without knowing which one i get. Is there a way to do it?

From trial and error it seems that Uri.parse does not work property on the second type as it does not add the prefix file:/// to it.

URI.fromFile does not work on the first type as it as it becomes file:///content:/.....etc

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add the "file:///" to the local path?

Comment: I get the path using context. GetFilesDir so it does not have have file:///

Comment: I guess I can add it using string manipulation but it seems like an extra overhead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File file = new File(path);
if(file.exists()) {
    return Uri.fromFile(file);
}
else {
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```